# trying to set the text above the Image in ImageTextButton on libGdx

Tags: libgdx, imagebutton

i'm using LIBGDX.

i'm trying to set a text string in the center of an image, and use it as a clickable button.

unfortunately i didn't find a solution for it.

Comment: Can please post what you have tried so far?

Comment: `ImageTextButton.ImageTextButtonStyle style = new ImageTextButton.ImageTextButtonStyle(startButtonStyle);  
        final ImageTextButton bb = new ImageTextButton(Integer.toString(levelNumber), style );  
        bb.stack(new Image(new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("levelButton.png")))));
        bb.getLabel().setAlignment(Align.center);`  
and it still doesn't work

Comment: If you don't know how to use the widget, the best way is to use `Table` and `Label`. I must to say, the UI from libgdx is a bit hard to make it work as expected If you are newbie, so try the simple way, and control the click event with your logic to change the image. If you make it, you could realize more complex component liked `ImageTextButton`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can with the getLabel method:

```
myButton.getLabel().setAlignment(Align.center);
```

https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Align.html

Answer (score 0):

By default, ImageTextButton contains 2 Actors in 1 row: Image then Label. To change position of the Label one may rebuild the underlying table cells just after creation of ImageTextButton:

```
  new ImageTextButton(...) {
    val label = getLabel
    val image = getImage
    clearChildren()
    add(image)
    row() // second row
    add(label)
  }
```

Now Label will be under the Image. Code is Scala.